# Form fields still treated as required even after setting #required to false

Tags: 8

I'm using `hook_form_alter` to remove the "required" setting for a couple of fields, specifically the *First name* and *Last Name* fields on the Address form.

Here's my code, where I provide a callback function for `#after_build` to remove the required setting:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'listing_edit_form') {
    $form['address']['widget'][0]['address']['#after_build'][] = '_mymodule_customize_address';
  }
}

function _mymodule_customize_address($element, $form_state) {
  $element['given_name']['#required'] = false;
  $element['family_name']['#required'] = false;
  return $element;
}
```

The problem is that after I submit the form, the fields are still treated as required, which means that if I don't enter any data for them the submit fails with an error message telling me that those fields are required.

Note that even if I hide the fields by setting `#access` to `false`, the form submit will still complain that they are required. So it seems to be a backend issue with the Address module.

I have:

```
Drupal                  8.7.1
drupal/address          1.6.0
commerceguys/addressing 1.0.3
commerceguys/enum       1.0
commerceguys/intl       1.0.4
```

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Entity field widgets set #required according to the field definition and this is what you have to change. It doesn't work to change it afterwards in the form, because entities are validated when submitted.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried unset() on the #required element, rather than making it false?

Comment: Thanks, @rivimey. Using `unset` worked!